# Indirection requires pointer operand ('double' invalid) как исправить

Tags: c, типы-данных

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define M_SQRT

double x;
double A;
double tan(double );
double cos(double );

int main(void )
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    printf("\n Введіть х:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    if( x < 1 && x> -1 ){
        A = (( 1 / tan(x) ) - ( ( 2*x ) / (x - 0.4) ) + ( M_SQRT * cos(x*x*x) ) );
        printf("\n Значення виразу дорівнює:\n %lf", &A);
    }
    else
        printf("\n Введене число не відповідає ОДЗ");
}
```

Comment: Однако новое слово в программировании - `double main(void )` я еще ни у кого не встречал...

Comment: В вашем коде, не считая неверного объявления `main`, нет объявления x, A, M_SQRT - это просто кусок чего-то нерабочего. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Фрагмент мы не сможем скомпилировать чтобы посмотреть вывод компилятора.

Comment: Понял, кинул полный код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас пустой `#define M_SQRT`. Это значит, что код

```
(M_SQRT * cos(x*x*x))
```

превращается в

```
(* cos(x*x*x))
```

А это уже разыменование указателя. `cos` возвращает `double`, а не указатель.

Comment: Большое спасибо))